# Issue with failing to detect peers via Bootnode on Local Network

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

I am attempting to connect various nodes to my private blockchain on my local network using a bootnode to discover peers. Connecting the peers on the local machine running the bootnode is possible, but when attempting to connect a peer from another machine, it does not work.

The following command is used to start the bootnode:

```
bootnode -nodekey boot.key -verbosity 9 -addr 192.168.254.85:30310
```

I am using this command to connect to the network via the bootnode:

```
geth --datadir node2/ --syncmode 'full' --port 30312 --rpc -rpcaddr 'localhost' --rpcport 8502 --rpcapi 'personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner' --bootnodes 'enode://4502006cbeb7c4f6a7bef61235f70c12406ed2b9f70dbab48202ab82e9f22367b685d7370ab864000406d3d5b1e8627c9ec2cd21720c366112663bede7cd27d4@192.168.254.85:0?discport=30310' --networkid 40152 --gasprice '0' --unlock '0x0888dBFf4Ac86aBE76963c7F2C339a6475CcAd2A' --password node2/password.txt --mine --allow-insecure-unlock console
```

Occasionally when running the bootnode the following error will occur (Invalid IP in response record)

[image: geth]

It successfully executes, but once the geth command line appears, it continues to look for peers without finding any. We've opened UDP and the necessary ports.

What could be the issue?